# How to display multiple sets of values without database in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm sure this is easy with Arrays but I don't seem to get how to do it as I need multiple sets of data

relevant PHP for 1 set, there may be 3-4 of these

```
$title="Slide Title";
$desc="Slide description";
$buttonlink="Button Link";
$button="Button";
```

PHP foreach of the sets (obviously this doesn't work because I don't have the set defined and don't know how to define it in the correct way)

```
 <?php foreach ($set[] ){ ?>  
  <div class="item">
          <img src="<?php  $slider ?>" alt="">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1><?php  echo $title ;?></h1>
              <p><?php  echo  $desc ;?></p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="<?php echo  $butonlink ;?>" role="button"><?php echo  $button ;?></a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

So basically how can I define each of the sets so I can use it in a single foreach statement that will output my desired set of variables.

Comment: Please read the manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php You will be faster in reading than we can type!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply array task, see this example:

```
<?php

$sets = array (
    array (
        'img'        => 'file.png',
        'title'      => 'Slide Title 1',
        'desc'       => 'Slide description 1',
        'buttonlink' => 'Button Link 1',
        'button'     => 'Button 1'
    ),
    array (
        'img'        => 'file.png',
        'title'      => 'Slide Title 2',
        'desc'       => 'Slide description 2',
        'buttonlink' => 'Button Link 2',
        'button'     => 'Button 2'
    )
);

foreach ($sets as $key => $set) {
?>
    <div class="<?php echo $key == 0 ? 'item active' : 'item'; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $set['img'] ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1><?php echo $set['title'] ;?></h1>
                <p><?php echo  $set['desc'] ;?></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="<?php echo $set['butonlink'] ;?>" role="button"><?php echo $set['button'] ;?></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: this is perfect. thanks. just one more thing. is there a way I can get the first item to show class="item active".

Comment: @SaudKazia: sure, there is more ways how to do that, I've updated my post... I choose the one using `$key` and ternary operator.

Comment: You are a star!!. Thanks a lot.